# Finishing a Windows Phone 8 app - is it different to WP7?

Tags: windows-phone-8

This may seem an odd question , but I'm just wondering if the process of finalising a WP8 app is different to a WP7 app.

In WP7 when I am ready to publish an app I just go into the Debug/Bin folder upload the XAP top Dev Center. However, when I do this with WP8 apps they never serve ads. Also the XAP is always called something like AppName_AnyCPU_Debug.xap compared to just AppName.xap in WP7 apps (using VS2010).

I know with Windows 8 you do something different, but is it the same in WP8?

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, its same in Windows phone 8.

But dont forget to check the project for store requirements.

Here is the link for more info on Store test kit
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394032%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about windows phone 7 but in windows phone 8 *_AnyCPU_Debug.xap means that xap is targeted for any CPU architecture(x86 or ARM) currently all windows phone CPU are ARM based. and secondly _Debug means that the xap is build as debug and that is not a good idea to publish the as the xap will contain unnecessary debug symbols and effect app performance. alwasy use build mode release when every you are publishing your app.